# bags file to excel

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,
i want to cconvert bags file to array (excel for example).
there is any solution to do this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/231109/bags-file-to-excel/) by [Emilien](https://answers.ros.org/users/26246/emilien/) on ROS Answers with karma: 167 on 2016-04-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are a couple of good posts about converting bag files to CSV, which can be imported into excel: http://answers.ros.org/question/9102/how-to-extract-data-from-bag/ and http://answers.ros.org/question/55037/is-there-a-way-to-save-all-rosbag-data-into-a-csv-or-text-file/

For the very simple case of extracting a simple message on a single topic, `rostopic echo -b file.bag -p /topic` works quite well.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Emilien](https://answers.ros.org/users/26246/emilien/) on 2016-04-05**:
thank you very much